# Unable to access the shared memory contents

Tags: c, unix

I 'm working on a sample program on mmap and shared memory. Here is the piece of code I was trying,

Process B

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/mman.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<malloc.h>

typedef struct sh_mem_t{
 int offset;
 char *buffer;
}sh_mem;

int main(){
 int fd;
 sh_mem *shm_obj;

 fd = shm_open("/myshm",O_RDWR,0777);
 if(fd == -1){
  perror("fd:ERROR");
  return -1;
 }

 shm_obj = mmap(0,sizeof(sh_mem),PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,fd,0);
 if(shm_obj == MAP_FAILED){
  perror("shm_obj:ERROR");
  return -1;
 }

 printf("\n offset : %d \n",shm_obj->offset);
// printf("\n Good work! : %s \n",shm_obj->buffer);

 return 0;
}
```

Process A

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/mman.h>
#include<sys/sem.h>

typedef struct sh_mem_t{
  int offset;
  char *buffer;
}sh_mem;

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
  int file_size = 0;
  int fd_sh = 0;
  sh_mem *shmptr = NULL;
  int fd = 0;
  char offset[2];
  int no_bytes_read = 0;
  int read_size = 10;
  int count = 0;
  int ret_val = 0;

  /* Variables for semaphore */
  int ret = 0;
  int semid = 0;
  key_t sem_key = 0;
  struct sembuf op[1];

  union semun{
   int val;
   struct semid_ds *buf;
   unsigned short *array;
  };
  union semun arg;

  /* Validate the i/p parameters */
  if(argc < 3){
   perror("argc:Did u forget the I/P file and the count 0?");
   return -1;
  }
  printf("File : %s",argv[1]);

  count = atoi(argv[2]);

  /* Create a semaphore */
  semid = semget(sem_key,1,IPC_CREAT | 0777);
  if(semid == -1){
   perror("semid:");
   return -1;
  }
  arg.val = 1;
  ret = semctl(semid,0,SETVAL,arg);

  /* Open the file to read the contents */
  fd = open(argv[1],O_RDONLY);

  /* Calculate the total size of the file */
  file_size = lseek(fd,0,SEEK_END);
  lseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET);
  printf("\n File Size is : %d \n",file_size);

  /* Create a new memory object */
  fd_sh = shm_open("/myshm",O_RDWR | O_CREAT,0777);

  /* Set the memory object's size */
  if((ftruncate(fd_sh,sizeof(sh_mem))) == -1){
   perror("ftruncate:ERROR");
   return -1;
  }

  /* Map the Memory object */
 shmptr = mmap(0,sizeof(sh_mem),PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,fd_sh,0);

  /* Allocate the memory for the buffer */
  shmptr->buffer = malloc((sizeof(char)*file_size));

  printf("\nThe Map address is : 0x%08x\n",shmptr);


 /* Copy the contents to the shared memory */
  read(fd,&offset,1);

  if(count == 0){
   shmptr->offset = 0;
  }


  while(shmptr->offset < file_size){

    /* Semaphore section Start */
    op[0].sem_num=0;
    op[0].sem_op=-1;
    op[0].sem_flg=0;

    semop(semid,op,1);
    printf("\n ProcessA Entering! \n");

    printf("\n initial offset value : %d \n",shmptr->offset);

    if(shmptr->offset > 0){
     shmptr->buffer = shmptr->buffer + shmptr->offset;
     ret_val = lseek(fd,shmptr->offset,SEEK_SET);
    }

    no_bytes_read = read(fd,shmptr->buffer,read_size);

    shmptr->offset = (read_size + shmptr->offset);
    printf("\n offset : %d \n",shmptr->offset);
    printf("\n contents : %s \n",shmptr->buffer);

    sleep(10);

    op[0].sem_op = 1;
    semop(semid,op,1);
    printf("\n ProcessA Leaving ! \n");
    /* Semapore section End*/
  }

  /* Detach from the shared memory */
  shmdt(shmptr);

  close(fd);
  close(fd_sh);

  return 0;
}
```

I have process A, which has put the data into the shared memory containing the structure values offset and buffer. Process B wants to access the contents stored in the shared memory(offset,buffer), but I could able to access only offset. When tried to access the buffer i'm getting a segmentation fault. Why am i getting a seg fault. As the shared object is mapped to the shared memory.

Process A will put 10 bytes into the shared memory and will go to sleep, then again it continues to put the next 10 bytes and so on.

Comment: If you need to store pointers in SHM then resort to storing offsets from start of SHM. Of course the target is pointing within SHM in that case.

Comment: @Sparkot: I could not get "resort to storing offsets from the start of SHM". Could you please explain.

Comment: Where are you allocating `buffer`? on the heap?

Comment: @Sparkot: yes, I'm allocating buffer on the heap.

Comment: I got you . You are asking me to catch the starting loc of the shmptr->buffer in a temp pointer, as i'm advancing the heap every time i update the contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When tried to access the buffer i'm getting a segmentation fault.

`buffer` is declared as `pointer` as part of your mapped memory:

```
typedef struct sh_mem_t{
 int offset;
 char *buffer;
}sh_mem;
```

Transferring pointers between processes does not make sense, since the pointer does not have any meaning in the slave process - the data it points to still resides in the master process.

You need to include the actual data you want to transfer from master to slave process:

```
typedef struct sh_mem_t{
 int offset;
 char buffer[BUFSIZE];
}sh_mem;
```

---

With the updated code in the question, the following changes are necessary to make it work:

- In **both A and B**, change the declaration of the shared memory struct to something like

```
   typedef struct sh_mem_t{
     int offset;
     char buffer[1024];
   }sh_mem;
```

- In **A**, remove the `malloc()` for `shmptr->buffer`. Also remove the line where you adjust the buffer by adding the offset (`shmptr->buffer = shmptr->buffer + shmptr->offset;`) - that needs to be handled differently, if you still need it
- In **B**, uncomment the line which prints the `Good work!` output.

With these changes, I was able to start the `A` process like `./A data.txt 0`. When I then start the `B` process, it prints both offset and buffer content, as it was last printed by the `A` process.

**Some additional remarks**

- You should use a header file to declare the `sh_mem` struct, and include this file in both your `.c` files, to make sure the declaration is consistent between `A` and `B`.
- With the solution I posted above, the application will crash with file sizes > 1024. You need to handle this accordingly, to make sure to not exceed the buffer size.

---

**Why isnt it working with pointers**

You can not access (non-shared) memory from the master process in the slave process, especially not by simply passing a pointer through the shared memory (this would make the shared memory concept obsolete). The memory which you allocated with `malloc()` in your master process is not part of the shared memory segment, so it is not accessible from the slave process.

In addition, `mmap()`, by default, is not guaranteed to return the same virtual address in both processes. So, even when you pass a pointer which points to a location **inside** the shared memory segment in the master, it does not point anywhere useful inside the slave process, unless you pass specific parameters to `mmap()`. See [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mmap64.3.html) for more details.

Comment: I tried what you told above, but its not working. buffer is prinitng some garbage value.

Comment: You need to initialize it in your master process. I will update my answer to give some hint

Comment: You should add some code from Process A to your question - without this, it is difficult to analyze the issue

Comment: Yes Andreas. You are correct. It works with arrays. But why isnt it working with pointers. I had a temp pointer to point to the start of the loc as shmptr->buffer which is advancing may not know the start of the loc. (shmptr->buffer = buff). But still it was not coming